# How to apply html stylistic tags to conditional statements?

Tags: html, tags, conditional-statements

I do not know anything about coding and html.

I am trying to create a kind of calculator that detects upper bounds. For example, a number is read and if it surpasses the number 20, the box should highlight red. See below for what I have come up with so far:

```
  <head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <style> .red{
         color: red;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Length" id="length">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Width" id="width">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Height" id="height">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Weight" id="weight">
      
    <script>
      function condition()
      {
       var len=document.getElementById("length").value);
       var wid=document.getElementById("width").value);
       var hei=document.getElementById("height").value);
       var wei=document.getElementById("weight").value);
     if (len >="20"){
   <p class="red">This is some paragraph with red color.</p> //<<<This is where I have the issue. I do not know how to display the color after it is read and accepted.
      }
      </script>
    <button type ="button" onclick="condition()">Calculate</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would guide you to check up on tutorials on DOM manipulation, that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you were trying to do. If you want the box to be red, just change the `document.getElementById("target")` to width or whatever you need, and then in the style in the .red class change `color` to `border-color`. After that, you need to make a reset mechanism so it won't stay red the next time you press the button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style>
      .red {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>

    <input type="number" placeholder="Length" id="length">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Width" id="width">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Height" id="height">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Weight" id="weight">

    <p id="target"></p>

    <button type="button" onclick="condition()">Calculate</button>

    <script>
      function condition() {
        let len = document.getElementById("length").value;
        let wid = document.getElementById("width").value;
        let hei = document.getElementById("height").value;
        let wei = document.getElementById("weight").value;

        if (len >= 20) {
          let target = document.getElementById("target");
          target.innerText = "This is some paragraph with red color.";
          target.classList.add("red");
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```